# I want to dubug lambda, but cdk synth does not include Lambda Resource, when it is deployed by pipeline stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-sam-cli

I am struggling to debug lambdas managed by CDK.

My CDK source is almost same to the sample below provided by AWS.

**https://github.com/aws-samples/cdk-pipelines-demo/tree/typescript**

The source structure is as follows:

```
--project_dir/
   |_cdk.json
   |_pipelines_webinar/
       |_lambda/
          |_handler.ts    <====== I WANT TO EXECUTE AND DEBUG ON LOCAL THIS.
   |_pipeline_stack.ts
   |_pipelines_webinar_stack.ts
   |_webservice_stage.ts
```

I think that it needs to use SAM CLI to run and debug locally.

But, If I run cdk synth to create SAM Template,
Lambda function (Type: AWS::Lambda::Function) does not exist in the created SAM Template.

I think this behavior is because lambda is deployed by CDK pipeline.

Here's how to reproduce the situation:

```
git clone -b typescript https://github.com/aws-samples/cdk-pipelines-demo.git
cd cdk-pipelines-demo
npm install
cdk synth > template.yml
```

**Q. Is there any way to run and debug lambda locally in this situation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you gave, the lambda function is instantiated in a stack which is deployed under the `WebServiceStage` pipeline stage.  For pipeline stages `cdk synth` bundles the function in a JSON file inside `cdk.out/` and includes a reference to this template as part of `template.yml`.  The lambda is passed in as an artifact, which means that it won't be written to `template.yml` directly.

A workaround would be to create a new file `lambda-app.ts` that instantiates the PipelinesWebinar Stack

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
import 'source-map-support/register';
import { App } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { PipelinesWebinarStack } from './pipelines_webinar/pipelines_webinar_stack';

const app = new App();

new PipelinesWebinarStack(app, 'PipelineStack');

app.synth();
```

Then compile that with `tsc`, and make cdk synth use that file with:-

```
cdk synth --app lambda-app.js --no-staging > template.yml
```

Then you should be able to find the logical ID in `template.yml` and run

```
sam invoke local <logicalId>
```

to run it locally

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am finally able to execute lambda on local.